# How to convert OpenGL 3 code to OpenGL 2 code?

Tags: opengl

I plan use OpenGL 3.0 to make a future application, mostly because of the good tutorials with it, and clean code! Though I do know that many computers still don't support OpenGL 3.0, are their any efficient ways to convert OpenGL 3.0 to 2.0?

Comment: I removed all references to C++ because OpenGL is language-agnostic. The language used to call the API is irrelevant.

Comment: Most OpenGL 3 features are available in OpenGL 2 through extensions, with generally only cosmetic changes to the API.

Comment: Are we talking "OpenGL" or "OpenGL ES" - afaik most computers supporting OpenGL run on OpenGL 3 or 4, whereby most OpenGL ES -using systems run on version 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I plan use OpenGL 3.0 to make a future application

In fact,using OpenGL 3.0 your application may hardly be called "future".OpenGL 3.0 is very old.[Versions](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL) 3.0 - 3.2 are transitional versions- from the old  OpenGL 2.x, to the new modern fully programmable OpenGL,which starts from the version 3.3 onward.So, yeah, you can use V3.0 mostly with no worry as most of the dedicated  GPUs,even relatively old still usually support V3.2.But if you want to invest into "future application", as you put it,OpenGL 3.3 (at least) is the way to go,and unless you plan to target really old (before the year 2010) harware ,you should be fine with it.

> are their any efficient ways to convert OpenGL 3.0 to 2.0?

Now,that depends how you use OpenGL.In 3,0 you can still write your app using the fixed OpenGL 2.x API.From the other hand,you can use shaders and all sort of extensions and using programmable pipeline.If you select second option then porting to OpenGL 2.x can be somewhat problematic.But if you stick to the fixed pipeline (still can use shaders) you are going to be fine.My personal advice - DON"T use DEPRECATED (fixed) PIPELINE ANYMORE.